# jQuery owl carousel defining options using variable

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Currently looping through a few carousels on the page but am trying to provide different options for each depending on the values placed in attribute. It loads fine but it will not apply the options.

Page Code

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" data-plugin-options='{"dots": true, "autoplay": false, "autoplayTimeout": 3000, "loop": false, "margin": 10, "nav": true, "responsive": {"0": {"items":2 }, "600": {"items": 4 }, "1024": {"items": 6 }, "1400": {"items": 6 }, "1920": {"items": 10}}}'>
....
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.owl-carousel').each( function () {
        
        var $owl = $(this);
        $owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
        
        $owl.html($owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').html()).removeClass('owl-loaded');
        
        var options = $(this).attr('data-plugin-options').substring(1, $(this).attr('data-plugin-options').length - 1).trim();
        
        $owl.owlCarousel({ 
            options
        });
        
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `options` from a string into a JSON object before you pass it to Owl

Try this:

```
$owl.owlCarousel(
   JSON.parse(options)
);
```